# Is there anything like JasperForm

Tags: forms, jasperserver

I am using Jaspersoft iReport & Jasperserver,

I want to take many input from user in Jasperserver & using that values,want to generate dynamic query mysql at back end in server to show report.

Comment: You can use JasperReports Server's input controls to populate your query (if I'm understanding your needs correctly).

Comment: how to use it,is there any good tutorials u have

Comment: Are you using the professional or community version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JasperReports Server's input controls to populate your query. You can view documentation on the JasperForge site at http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation?version=5218 - look for the JasperReports Server User Guide, or if you have purchased the professional edition, you can view it through the support portal at http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation?version=5218.